# Code sending bad message in plugin on minecraft

Tags: plugins, minecraft

im working on plugin, but when player do a command in game, "sender" do four same messages...

[image]

```
      @EventHandler
  public void oncmd(PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent e) {

      List<String> block = Arrays.asList(":");

      block.forEach(all -> {

         if(e.getMessage().toLowerCase().contains(all.toLowerCase())) {
             e.getPlayer().sendMessage("§8[§aSystem§8] §cYou can't use this command!");
             e.setCancelled(true);
         }
      });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a char array with the characters which aren't allowed. After that you can use a simple for loop to iterate through all elements. Inside of this loop, you can now check if the command contains this character.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for-each loop instead of calling the `forEach` function. This will let you add a `break` statement, which will end the loop after it finds the first bad character:

```
      @EventHandler
  public void oncmd(PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent e) {

      List<String> block = Arrays.asList(":");

      for(String all : block) {

         if(e.getMessage().toLowerCase().contains(all.toLowerCase())) {
             e.getPlayer().sendMessage("§8[§aSystem§8] §cYou can't use this command!");
             e.setCancelled(true);
             break;
         }
      }

  }
```

Alternatively, if you want to stay with a more functional approach, you can use `anyMatch`:

```
      @EventHandler
  public void oncmd(PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent e) {

      List<String> block = Arrays.asList(":");

      if(block.stream().anyMatch(all -> e.getMessage().toLowerCase().contains(all.toLowerCase()))) {

         e.getPlayer().sendMessage("§8[§aSystem§8] §cYou can't use this command!");
         e.setCancelled(true);
      }

  }
```